# Firebase Admin Database Snapshot Data After Query?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

### Setup

*Let us imagine that this is my JSON data*

```
values: {
    a: {
        randomValue: "set",
        sorter: 1
    },
    b: {
        randomValue: "hat",
        sorter: 2
    }
}
```

I **can** retrieve data from my database with the admin database (from Cloud Functions) like this

```
admin.database().ref('values/a').once('value').then(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.val().randomValue + ' .. ' + snapshot.val().sorter);
});
```

***Output*** will be `set .. 1`.

## Problem

As soon as I attach a query to my request it stops working, i.e. it does not work like mentioned [in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-queries).
There they can *clearly* access `snapshot.val().height` **with a query**.

Although when I do my query like this

```
admin.database().ref('values').orderByChild('sorter').equalTo(1).once('value').then(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    console.log(snapshot.val().randomValue + ' .. ' + snapshot.val().sorter);
    console.log(snapshot.child('randomValue').val() + ' .. ' + snapshot.child('sorter').val());
}
```

The output will *suprisingly* be the following

```
a: {
    randomValue: "set",
    sorter: 1
}
undefined .. undefined
null .. null
```

So `snapshot.val()` does give me my full data, but not a single way of accessing will give me any data, just `undefined` or `null`! Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to access the fields as `snapshot.val().a.randomValue` in this case. Note that you're running the query against the `values` node, and not the `values/a` node. Therefore your result contains the `a` property.

**Update**

When you run the query against the `values` node, and subscribe to the [`value` event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#value) (which is what `once()` method does internally), you get the full value (parent key + child) of the query. To get only the child, you need subscribe to a [child event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#child-added). This is what the samples in the documentation do. For instance:

`admin.database().ref('values').orderByChild('sorter').equalTo(1).once('child_added').then(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    console.log(snapshot.val().randomValue + ' .. ' + snapshot.val().sorter);
    console.log(snapshot.child('randomValue').val() + ' .. ' + snapshot.child('sorter').val());
});`

will yield the output you're trying to get:

`{ randomValue: 'set', sorter: 1 }
set .. 1
set .. 1`

Comment: oh Thank you! Now I get it. I need to use the 'child_added' event.